# How can I convert a stim signal from analog to digital?

Tags: operational-amplifier, clock, pspice, orcad

I want to get a digital signal from dstm1,2,3,4, but I can't.

What's the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your schematic is illegible.

Comment: You should swap your opamp inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this, for example ...
You should swap your inputs.

[image]

Or this one ...

[image]

Or this one ...

[image]